# display dynamic table in 2 columns for printout

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table

I have a table thats dynamically generated. It shows what work certain employees conducted for a given period, with each work as a new row and total of 4 columns per work with info on time used etc. So the data looks like

Worker1
mailservice | 2h | 3$ | 6$
phonecalls | 1.4h | 2$ | 2.8$

Worker2
mailservice | 4h | 3$ | 12$
storage | 11h | 8$ | 88$

Worker3
phonecalls | 23h | 3$ | 69$

and so on. The number of rows for each worker varies, depending what he/she did during the time frame. Same for number of workers in a given time frame. So I end up with a nice table full of data, that looks great on screen. But now I need to print it out, and to save paper it has to go in 2 columns (landscape format), like this

```
Worker 1           worker3
....               ....

worker2            worker4
....               ....
```

I have no clue how to get the table to wrap into a second column on the page before continueing on the next page. Page break etc is quite clear though.

Any help would be appreciated.

edit: Here's the generated html code so far (nothing exotic though):

```
<div class="halfboxR" id="do-print" style="border:1px solid #000;"><table border="0" class="fontxsmall">
<tr><td class="fett lrgfont" colspan="4">AUSWERTUNG vom xx.yy.20zz bis xx.yy.20zz</td></tr>
    <tr class="fett">
    <td class="lrgfont">Employee 1</td>
    <td>von:  <br>bis: &nbsp;</td>
    <td> h</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fett">
    <td>T&auml;tigkeit</td>
    <td>Wert &euro; (je)</td>
    <td>Anzahl</td>
    <td>Gesamt &euro;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
          <td>Kundenkontakte telefonisch</td>
          <td>xy</td>
          <td>192</td>
          <td>zz</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="fett">
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td>Summe:</td>
      <td>zz &euro;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="fett">
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td>Soll:</td>
      <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td colspan="4" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

    <tr class="fett">
    <td class="lrgfont">Employee 2</td>
    <td>von:  <br>bis: &nbsp;</td>
    <td> h</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fett">
    <td>T&auml;tigkeit</td>
    <td>Wert &euro; (je)</td>
    <td>Anzahl</td>
    <td>Gesamt &euro;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email allgemein</td>
        <td>xy</td>
        <td>99</td>
        <td>zz</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>Liefersperre</td>
        <td>xy</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>zz</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>abw. Lieferadresse / AP</td>
        <td>xy</td>
        <td>76</td>
        <td>zz</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>Packstation</td>
        <td>xy</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>zz</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>Dubletten</td>
        <td>xy</td>
        <td>130</td>
        <td>zz</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>Kundenbetreuung</td>
        <td>xy</td>
        <td>186</td>
        <td>zz</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td>Kundenkontakte telefonisch</td>
          <td>xy</td>
          <td>518</td>
          <td>zz</td>
          </tr><tr>
          <td>Kundenkontakte telefonisch cmp2</td>
          <td>xy</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>zz</td>
          </tr><tr>
          <td>Kundenkontakte telefonisch cmp3</td>
          <td>xy</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>zz</td>
          </tr><tr>
          <td>Kundenkontakte telefonisch cmp4</td>
          <td>xy</td>
          <td>62</td>
          <td>zz</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="fett">
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td>Summe:</td>
      <td>zz &euro;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="fett">
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td>Soll:</td>
      <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td colspan="4" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

    <tr class="fett">
    <td class="lrgfont">Employee 3</td>
    <td>von:  <br>bis: &nbsp;</td>
    <td> h</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fett">
    <td>T&auml;tigkeit</td>
    <td>Wert &euro; (je)</td>
    <td>Anzahl</td>
    <td>Gesamt &euro;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Auftrag</td>
        <td>xy</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>zz</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>Adress&auml;nderungen</td>
        <td>xy</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>zz</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>Email allgemein</td>
        <td>xy</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>zz</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td>Kundenkontakte telefonisch</td>
          <td>xy</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>zz</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="fett">
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td>Summe:</td>
      <td>zz &euro;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="fett">
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td>Soll:</td>
      <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td colspan="4" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

    <tr class="fett">
    <td class="lrgfont">Employee 4</td>
    <td>von:  <br>bis: &nbsp;</td>
    <td> h</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fett">
    <td>T&auml;tigkeit</td>
    <td>Wert &euro; (je)</td>
    <td>Anzahl</td>
    <td>Gesamt &euro;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email allgemein</td>
        <td>xy</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>zz</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td>Kundenkontakte telefonisch</td>
          <td>xy</td>
          <td>95</td>
          <td>zz</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="fett">
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td>Summe:</td>
      <td>zz &euro;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="fett">
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td>Soll:</td>
      <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td colspan="4" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

    <tr class="fett">
    <td class="lrgfont">Employee 5</td>
    <td>von:  <br>bis: &nbsp;</td>
    <td> h</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fett">
    <td>T&auml;tigkeit</td>
    <td>Wert &euro; (je)</td>
    <td>Anzahl</td>
    <td>Gesamt &euro;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Angebote</td>
        <td>xy</td>
        <td>573</td>
        <td>zz</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>Email allgemein</td>
        <td>xy</td>
        <td>115</td>
        <td>zz</td>
        </tr>
      <tr class="fett">
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td>Summe:</td>
      <td>zz &euro;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="fett">
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td>Soll:</td>
      <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td colspan="4" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
      </table></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your example code?

Comment: done, see the relevant part above

Comment: Can you please remove php code and add generated html (hopefully with more rows). You can go to view-source, or developer mode and copy it from there.

Comment: done. This will display in a box at the right side on screen (as intended, left side has the controls for the report, right side shows scrollable box with result of report requests), and I need it to be kinda 2 columns on print out as described above (currently it's on the left half of page only)

Comment: Hm..problem is that html table has already predefined structure, you can't really avoid it. There is an option to change display of table elements to "inline-block" (or whichever), but then you lose table properties. Maybe the best option is to avoid table in this situation. It can be done, but it's very ugly

Comment: it looks more and more like I will have to abandon the table here and display the results as single divs (with the layout mimicking the table); that way I could just float them around as I like for the print out formating then... hmm

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest enclosing all the tables in an outer div upon which you set some default width to.  Then place the tables inside that div, with a style of display: inline-block, and some width.  Then they should wrap just fine.

You'll want to do this using the @media query in CSS which you can read about here: [Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp).

Note that using this method, you could have a single column on your displayed page, and multiple columns on the printed page.

Comment: I have only one table that might be quite long depending on the time frame I select. How do I get that one table to wrap into 2 different divs that are side by side then? Of course I could create a table for each result (or keep the result data in divs) and then start floating those around until it looks like a table that wraps into 2 columns...